# how to take the 3 line of this write output

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I don't know how to take the 3rd line of this output.  Can someone help to take 3rd line of the Backup up column?  I want to take this date and hour to make some things, this is the output:

[image: output]

This is my code:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Veritas\NetBackup\bin"

$output = .\bpclimagelist.exe -ct 0

Write-Output $output | Format-list -Property Expires
```

I tried everything but I don't know to take this.

Comment: Looking at the image, it looks like the property `Expires` is an array of objects. In that case `$output.Expires[2].'Backed Up'` should give you the third value of this column. If that is not the case, do a `$output.Expires.GetType().FullName` to show what it really is.

Comment: actually is `$output` an object or string (`$output | Get-Member`)? because you receive it from bpclimagelist.exe and normaly you will get text / string and not an object.

Answer (score 0):

If $output is a String array:

```
$output[2].Substring(0,16)
```

If $output is Multi line String:

```
($output -Split "`n")[2].Substring(0,16)
```

You will get the date from 3rd line

If you want to list all dates then use

```
$output[2..$($output.Count - 1)]|Foreach{$_.Substring(0,16)}
```

Comment: if i want to take the policy column?, i just want to take some characters of 1 line of this column, thanks.